# Visual Studio UWP not launching when clicking the executable from the bin directory

Tags: windows, uwp

I am making a program for a friend, and when I run it using a build and run through visual studio it runs just fine, however when I go to run it directly from the file explorer (by going to bin/x64(or x86)/release/application.exe, it doesn't run. We have tried running it on both my computer along with his and we can't figure out why it won't launch. any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm on a time crunch.

Answer (score 4):

UWP apps run in sandbox. They're not the regular Windows desktop applications. It's impossible to launch the UWP apps by double clicking its `.exe` file.

You would have to find your app in Start menu. If you've debugged it in visual studio, it should be at the top of recently added apps and then, you could launch it from there.

Please read [What's a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide#secure) for more details.